# Cannot connect to chrome at localhost:22020 error using SetExperimentalOption debuggerAddress as localhost:22020

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I'm having real trouble to switch control from desktop application using let to a chrome web browser using selenium.

Here is what I have done:

I'm having an issue connecting to chrome debug port .

- Added chrome.exe to my environment variable path
- Configured the chrome debug port thru command line and specified port: 22020
- Added

  ```
  options.SetExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:22020")
  ```

But chrome keeps starting from a random port numbers , and I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot connect to chrome at localhost:22020
```

Please help

Comment: I would use another port... that one could be in use.

Answer (score 0):

While starting a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* using:

```
options.SetExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:22020")
```

this error message...

```
cannot connect to chrome at localhost:22020
```

...can occur due to a lot of reasons.

An immediate solution would be to shift from *`hostname:port`* to *`ip:port`* as follows:

```
options.SetExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:22020")
```

Some of the known reasons are:

- Port ***22020*** which may be blocked by some other services.
- Your system have security software installed that is listening on this port or using network web filtering.